# WSO2 - set PublishWSDL URI from registry

Tags: wsdl, wso2, wso2-esb

I have the following pass-through proxy in WSO2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="MyServiceName_V2" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
<target>
    <inSequence>
        <log level="full">
            <property name="state" value="before"/>
        </log>
        <send>
            <endpoint key="gov:path.to.the.endpoint.in.the.registry"/>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
</target>
<publishWSDL uri="http://localhost:myservice.svc?singleWsdl"></publishWSDL>
<parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter>
```

The endpoint for the service is in the registry, so I can deploy this proxy to any number of WSO2 servers (development, test, qa, ...), and the endpoint url will point to the correct server/url for each environment.

But the publishWSDL uri is currently hardcoded: it points directly to a fixed uri (currently on my development machine). I want to replace this by something that points to some value in the registry, just like the uri for the actual endpoint.

I've tried adding a wsdl endpoint, but that didn't work, because I think the wsdl endpoint isn't just the wsdl but a complete endpoint based on the wsdl.

I'm thinking that I should just replace the publishWsdl uri with some text content from the registry, but I have no idea how to first get the text content in the registry (in a WSO2 dev studio project in Eclipse), and then how to get that value from the registry into that uri property for the publishWsdl element.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I eventually did was remove the 'useOriginalwsdl' setting.

That setting was needed because each ESB server we had replaced the endpoints by its own name, while we wanted that endpoint to be the address of the load balancer. So we set the endpoints to that address in the WSDL, and set 'useOriginalwsdl' to true.

But it's much better to set the 'WSDLEPRPrefix' parameter in axis2.xml instead so when I found that setting, that's what we did.

Answer (score 3):

You can use WSO2 Registry to store WSDL files, and same can be referred in WSO2 ESB Proxy.

```
Ex: <publishWSDL key="conf:wsdls/MyService.wsdl"/>
```

**Storing WSDL Resource files in WSO2 Registry using wso2 develop studio.**

- Open WSO2 Registry perspective
- Add registry instance
- Add collection (wsdls directory in the given example)
  -
- Add resource (MyService.wsdl in the given example).The resource can
     be created using following methods

  - Uploading content from file (WSDL file from disc)
  - Create custom content (You can copy paste or write a new WSDL file in content  column)
  - Import content from URL (You can provide your WSDL URL of 
         already deployed service)

REF: https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS370/Managing+the+Registry

**Referring WSDL from Registry using wso2 developer studio**

1. Open WSO2 ESB Graphical perspective
2. Select Create a New Proxy Service and click Next
3. Type a unique name for the proxy service and select Proxy Service
4. Type Custom Proxy and Click on Finish
5. Right click on newly created proxy design and Select Show Properties View.
   In this Properties View for Proxy Service you can find multiple
   sections

   - Basic
   - Endpoint
   - Fault Sequence
   - In Sequence
   - Out Sequence
   - Parameters
   - Policy
   - Qos
   - WSDL
6. Scroll down to the WSDL section and Select Wsdl Type as REGISTRY_KEY(By default the value is NONE)
7. Click on /default/key value which shows you an ellipse button, click on eclipse button to select Wsdl Key from registry.
8. From the pop up window select registry link, which takes you to the Registry Browser
9. Create Registry Creation using by clicking on green + button.
10. Navigate to the wsdl resource and click ok.

REF:https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS370/Creating+ESB+Artifacts#CreatingESBArtifacts-Creatinganewproxyservic